# Assigning multiple attributes to Subprocess.Popen's STDOUT

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm making a multi - pinging software. For that I used subprocess.Popen to ping the devices. I didn't want the normal output to show, so I used STDOUT = DEVNULL to hide the text. Now I need the text to add to some log files for the user to check but I don't wish to show the text in the terminal either. Is there any way for me to assign two values to STDOUT - ex. stdout = (DEVNULL, PIPE) or is there any other value that will do the task I need?

Basically something like:

```
pop = subprocess.Popen([Some Command], shell = True, stdout = (subprocess.DEVNULL, subprocess.PIPE))
res = pop.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `stdout=PIPE` will not write to the terminal, so there is no need for using `DEVNULL` to inhibit the output. The problem is that with `PIPE` you first have to read the output into `res` and then write `res` to the logfile.

You can directly pass an open file as `stdout` to `Popen`:

```
with open('logfile', 'w') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ls"], stdout=f)
    proc.wait()
with open('logfile', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read())
```